# Why does the 'in' keyword claim it needs an iterable object?

Tags: python

```
>>> non_iterable = 1
>>> 5 in non_iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

>>> class also_non_iterable:
...     def __contains__(self,thing):
...         return True

>>> 5 in also_non_iterable()
True
>>> isinstance(also_non_iterable(), Iterable)
False
```

Is there a reason `in` keyword claims to want an iterable object when what it truly wants is an object that implements `__contains__`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It claims to want an iterable because, if the object's class does not implement an `__contains__` , then `in` tries to iterate through the object and check if the values are equal to the values yield by it.

An Example to show that -

```
>>> class C:
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return iter([1,2,3,4])
>>>
>>> c = C()
>>> 2 in c
True
>>> 5 in c
False
```

This is explained in [the documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in)

> For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, `x in y` is true if and only if `y.__contains__(x)` is true.
>
> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do define `__iter__()` , `x in y` is true if some value `z` with `x == z` is produced while iterating over `y` . If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if in raised that exception.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess the error message is just a little inexact, then.

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you tried contains first, failed and were falling back to iterations next then the iteration bit is where an exception would bubble up.  So the messaging is consistent with the point of non recoverable error.

Comment: And yes, that is also mentioned in the documentation - *If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if in raised that exception.* .

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a reason `in` keyword claims to want an iterable object when what it truly wants is an object that implements `__contains__`?

`x in thing` and `for x in thing` are very closely related. Almost everything that supports `x in thing` follows the rule that `x in thing` is true if and only if a for loop over `thing` will find an element equal to `x`. In particular, if an object supports iteration but not `__contains__`, Python will use iteration as a fallback for `in` tests.

The error message could say it needs `__contains__`, but that would be about as wrong as the current message, since `__contains__` isn't strictly necessary. It could say it needs a container, but it's not immediately clear what counts as a container. For example, dicts support `in`, but calling them containers is questionable. The current message, which says it needs an iterable, is about as accurate as the other options. Its advantage is that in practice, "is it iterable" is a better check than "is it a container" or "does it support `__contains__`" for determining whether actual objects support `in`.

Comment: They are related, yes, but still two different things. `for x in also_non_iterable()` will still raise a `TypeError`. So that's a separate error.
It seems easy enough to say `object is not iterable or a container` in place of the original error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different uses of `in`:

- test if a container has a value (eg. left argument implements `__contains__`)
- traverse through a sequence (eg. right argument is `Iterable`)

Comment: Good point.  But it would be very inefficient to iterate through a big list (loose usage here) from an object that had a \__contain__   Like say a  dict. Or even more so a set. So wouldnt a test for membership be treated differently from a sequence traversal and privilege a contain check first?